# How to Add Multiple NSDictionaries to NSArray in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

Here i had taken single dictionary and added it to Array,Now how do i do for Multiple Dictionaries?

```
[self.dict setObject:_firstNameText.text forKey:@"FirstName"];
 [self.dict setObject:_lastNameText.text forKey:@"LastName"];
 [self.dict setObject:_ageText.text forKey:@"Age"];
 [self.dict setObject:_emailText.text forKey:@"Email"];
 [self.dict setObject:_mobileNumberText.text forKey:@"MobileNumber"];
   NSLog(@"%@:",_dict);

 [self.arr addObject:self.dict];
                NSLog(@"%@:",_arr );
```

Comment: Not clear what you're asking

Comment: how to add multiple dictionaries to array?

Comment: What's the problem - just add these dictionaries to array

Comment: i had created a form with textfields , i had saved the data by pressing submit button in NSDictionary and added it to array, i did it for single user , how to save multiple users data ?

Comment: Do you add another dictionary to the array or do you change the same dictionary?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your question is okey

you should use `NSMutableArray` for first. Than you have to `addObject` for every NSDictionaries

```
[mutableArray addObject:Dictionary];
[mutableArray addObjects:@"here array of dictionaries"];
```

cheers

Comment: If `self.arr` isn't mutable `addObject:` won't compile. How do you create `array of dictionaries`?

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: You don't understand everything I wrote, read better my comment. And save time to me and other people